# 'router-outlet' is not a known element - angular

Tags: angular

When i start the angular application i get the following error,

```
Error: Template parse errors:
'router-outlet' is not a known element
.....
ng:///LayoutModule/LayoutComponent.html
```

**app.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    ...
    AppRoutesModule,
    LayoutModule,
    ...
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**app-routes.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
  ],
  exports: [
    RouterModule
  ],
  declarations: []
})
export class AppRoutesModule{ }
```

**layout.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [],
  declarations: [LayoutComponent, HeaderComponent]
})
export class LayoutModule { }
```

I did not import `RouterModule` in `LayoutModule` intentionally because the `AppRoutesModule` exports it already which should be available in the `LayoutModule`.

Is there any reason why it's not working?

Comment: But the `LayoutModule` *doesn't* import the `AppRoutesModule`.

Comment: my understanding was, if i import something in root module, then it's available in all it's feature modules ( eagerly loaded ). For eg, i need to only import `HttpClientModule` only on the root module then it's automatically available in the `core` , `layout` etc.. pls correct me if i am wrong

Comment: @DRB Yes, your understanding is true, but `AppRouterModule` is not root module, `AppModule` is. So, this makes `LayoutModule` a sibling of `AppRoutesModule`, as they are not linked in any way but both are imported in `AppModule`

Answer (score 2):

`LayoutComponent` is part of `LayoutModule`, So, Import `RouterModule` in `LayoutModule`. So that, angular recognizes `LayoutModule` as a part of `RouterModule`.

OR

Make `AppRoutesModule` a part of `LayoutModule`, by importing it in `LayoutModule`

'export' keyword allow class to be exported and 'import' keyword actually import any already exported class.

Comment: exactly, but author probably want's to have that router outlet in the whole app, in that case he probably find useful my answer :)

Comment: @Sh. Pavel RouterModule is already imported in main module inside the provided code.

Comment: I guess AppRoutesModule and LayoutModule are not linked, So, its important to import RouterModule in both files.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should to import RouterModule to your main module. Because you Main module does not see it, even if you exporting it from another module.

Your main module:

```
...
imports: [... RouterModule.forRoot(routes)], ...
```

In that case it would be visible globally.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to import `AppRoutesModule` in `LayoutModule`. Updated `LayoutModule` is as follows:

**layout.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [AppRoutesModule],
  declarations: [LayoutComponent, HeaderComponent]
})
export class LayoutModule { }
```